# Deployed silverlight application WCF Service error

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Ive created a Silverlight application and im using WCF service to access my database. It works fine debugging in visual studio but when i deploy it to my iis i get an error trying to access my database. Im not sure if its something ive done wrong setting up the service or an database access problem.

my connection string:

```
<add name="database" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Automationdev;Integrated Security=False;Pooling=False;User ID=Guest;Password=passwordz
```

**my service:**

> service name="PublishedSoftwareSilverlight.Web.Service1"
>
> endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"
>   bindingConfiguration="PublishedSoftwareSilverlight.Web.Service1.customBinding0"
>   contract="PublishedSoftwareSilverlight.Web.Service1"
>
> endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

**clientConfig**:

> endpoint address="http://localhost/SilverLight/Service1.svc"
>   binding="customBinding"
>                   bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_Service1" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1"
>                   name="CustomBinding_Service1"

Someone please help....Thank you.

Error:
Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Sun, 26 May 2013 07:59:58 UTC
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception
>   occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check
>   InnerException for exception details.   at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at
>   PublishedSoftwareSilverlight.ServiceReference1.AreaListCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>   at
>   PublishedSoftwareSilverlight.Models.ServiceInterface.client_AreaListCompleted(Object
>   sender, AreaListCompletedEventArgs e)    at
>   PublishedSoftwareSilverlight.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.OnAreaListCompleted(Object
>   state) Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0

Comment: Update: Found possible fix, but cant try till tuesday morning. If anyone has any points that may help just incase i havent fixed it. Please post still.

Comment: What is the inner exception? Do you get your webservice with no errors if you hit http://localhost/SilverLight/Service1.svc in a browser?